# Oracle Service Bus retrying service callout

Tags: osb, oracle-fusion-middleware

I am new to Oracle OSB and I am trying to invoke a service, but if the invocation fails, retry that invocation up to N times. If it fails N+1 times I want to log the occurence.

Can anyone help me or suggest me some documentation?

Cheers

Answer (score 3):

I think you have created following services already in your osb console:
1. Proxy Service
2. Business Service

I think you want to try to call the Service N extra times, that will make the last try as (N+1)th try or Nth retry.

Now, for retry mechanism, set Retry Count in [Transport Configuration of Business Service](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13159_01/osb/docs10gr3/consolehelp/businessServices.html#wp1095605) to N.

In case of failure of the Nth retry, you will receive an error back in your proxy service. Suppose you called Business Service from Route Node of Proxy Service. In this case, you can catch the error in RouteNode [Error Handler](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13159_01/osb/docs10gr3/consolehelp/proxyerrors.html#wp1243530). You can log the details here.

Comment: Fully correct answer. I just have to add than for some backend services it is required to update the message with "This is a re-sending" flag to allow for duplicate delivery checking; for such services the retry would have to be done manually -- catch in error handler and retry after update. Pain in the butt, those.